# Ergodicity of measure induced by generic points in Birkhoff's ergodic theorem

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, $T:X\to X$ the shift map, and $\mu$ a $T$-invariant probability measure on $X$. A point $x \in X$ is **generic** if 
$$
\lim\, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i<n} \chi_{\sigma}(T^{i}(x))
$$
exists for every finite binary string $\sigma$ (so $\chi_{\sigma}$ is the characteristic function of the basic clopen cylinder set determined by $\sigma$). By Birkhoff's ergodic theorem, $\mu$-almost all $x$ are generic. Now when $x$ is generic, the set function $\mu_{x}$ defined on basic clopen cylinders by
$$
\mu_{x}(\sigma) = \lim\, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i<n} \chi_{\sigma}(T^{i}(x))
$$
is actually (extendable to) a $T$-invariant measure. [This page](http://pfzhang.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/ergodic-decomposition/) claims that this measure is in fact ergodic.

**Question: Why is $\mu_{x}$ ergodic when $x$ is generic?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x$ can be generic by your definition while $\mu_x$ is not ergodic:

[A generic point for a non-ergodic measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28817/a-generic-point-for-a-non-ergodic-measure?rq=1)

The page you linked is only considering points that are generic for ergodic measures.